# Why is the ripple frequency in dc side of 3 phase full wave converter is considered to be 6 times that of ac side?

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier, bridge-rectifier

I can't find why is the ripple frequency in dc side of 3 phase full wave converter is considered to be 6 times that of ac side? [image: Ower]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are 6 peaks per cycle in the combined input waveforms, and the three input sines are phased in such a way that none of these peaks coincide in time.

Think about it.  Each input sine has two peaks, one positive and one negative per cycle.  Three such sines therefore have a total of six peaks.  With the three input sines 120° (1/3 cycle) apart, there will be one peak each 1/6 of a cycle, or every 60°.

This is a rare case where a simulator might actually be useful.

Simulation of 3 sines 120° apart and its input and output waveforms.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Perhaps a nomination for the Bob Pease of the year award.